# How to change machines on a nlkvm-4 kvm swtich

Tags: hardware, switch-statement, kvm

Hi
I recently got my hands on a newlink nlkvm-4 4 port kvm switch that came to me without the user manual. I googled and found other kvm user guides but I could not find the newlink nlkvm-4 manual on line. I have 2 machines hooked up to it at the moment and have no idea how to switch from one to the other. Could anyone who has one let me know the function key sequence to switch and any other function key sequences that might be helpful to me.
Thanks
A

Comment: I assume you tried scroll lock x2 and up/down? Scroll lock at least seems to be pretty universal these days as the access key.

Comment: I'll try that. I could find no info on this out there

Comment: tried scroll lock x 2 and ctrl x 2. neither of these worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a reference to hitting the leftside CTRL twice followed by a number from 1 to 4. So CTRL CTRL 1 for port 1 I'm guessing.  I'd try it using the top row of numbers and then with the number pad numbers.  From the sound of it, you're not holding down the control key.

Comment: thats it. Thank you. Not intuitive if you don't have instructions

Comment: btw where did you find the reference? do you have the url?

Comment: I googled for "newlink kvm hotkey" (no quotes though) and found this guy complaining that it didn't work anymore on his kvm:    http://www.tech-pc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=66869&view=previous

Answer (score 0):

I've used this before, I might be late in replying to this forum ... in order to use this KVM switch, all you have to do is press CTRL twice followed by a number from 1-4 ... so it will be something like,

CTRL CTRL 1 (for first screen)
CTRL CTRL 2 (for second screen) and so on ...

You will notice the light illuminate on the KVM, whichever screen is on !!!